# "Column Count Doesn't Match Value at row." Missing t_stamp which is auto generated

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, where-clause

My issue is that I am using a stored procedure to copy everything from one table into a new table and in the new table. I am also auto generating a timestamp column in the new table. I know the issue has to do with this t_stamp column. I just don't know how to handle that. Here is my code in the stored procedure: Both tables will be exactly the same except the new table will have a t_stamp column just to keep track of the date. The reason i created the second table is the first one gets cleared every day while the second one is need to keep record.

```
    CREATE DEFINER="root"@"localhost" PROCEDURE "backupSAPTables"()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sap.process_order_confirmation_detail_backup
    SELECT ProcessOrder, ConfirmationSeq, Material, ByProductIndicator, Quantity, UOM, Batch, MovementType, ManufDate, GI_GR_Indicator, GMP_Indicator, GMP_Production_Date, GMP_Production_Time, GMP_Fat, GMP_Fat_UOM, GMP_Protein, GMP_Protein_UOM, GMP_Total_Solids, GMP_Total_Solids_UOM, FillerName, ChangedDate, ChangedTime, ChangedBy
    FROM sap.process_order_confirmation_detail
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ProcessOrder, ConfirmationSeq, Material, ByProductIndicator, Quantity, UOM, Batch, MovementType, ManufDate, GI_GR_Indicator, GMP_Indicator, GMP_Production_Date, GMP_Production_Time, GMP_Fat, GMP_Fat_UOM, GMP_Protein, GMP_Protein_UOM, GMP_Total_Solids, GMP_Total_Solids_UOM, FillerName, ChangedDate, ChangedTime, ChangedBy 
                 FROM sap.process_order_confirmation_detail_backup 
                 WHERE (sap.process_order_confirmation_detail.ProcessOrder = sap.process_order_confirmation_detail_backup.ProcessOrder and sap.process_order_confirmation_detail.ConfirmationSeq = sap.process_order_confirmation_detail_backup.ConfirmationSeq and sap.process_order_confirmation_detail.Material = sap.process_order_confirmation_detail_backup.Material));
                 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide all columns of the target table for insert, then you need to enumerate all of the target columns in the `insert` clause, so it is explicit which value should be assigned to which column. The database will then assign the relevant value to the "missing" columns (default if there is one, else `null`).

You stated that the structures of the tables are the same (apart from the auto-generated timestamp column), so that should be:

```
INSERT INTO sap.process_order_confirmation_detail_backup ( 
    ProcessOrder, 
    ConfirmationSeq, 
    Material, 
    ByProductIndicator, 
    Quantity, 
    UOM, 
    Batch, 
    MovementType, 
    ManufDate, 
    GI_GR_Indicator, 
    GMP_Indicator, 
    GMP_Production_Date, 
    GMP_Production_Time, 
    GMP_Fat, 
    GMP_Fat_UOM, 
    GMP_Protein, 
    GMP_Protein_UOM, 
    GMP_Total_Solids, 
    GMP_Total_Solids_UOM, 
    FillerName, 
    ChangedDate, 
    ChangedTime, 
    ChangedBy
)
SELECT 
    ProcessOrder, 
    ConfirmationSeq, 
    Material, 
    ByProductIndicator, 
    Quantity, 
    UOM, 
    Batch, 
    MovementType, 
    ManufDate, 
    GI_GR_Indicator, 
    GMP_Indicator, 
    GMP_Production_Date, 
    GMP_Production_Time, 
    GMP_Fat, 
    GMP_Fat_UOM, 
    GMP_Protein, 
    GMP_Protein_UOM, 
    GMP_Total_Solids, 
    GMP_Total_Solids_UOM, 
    FillerName, 
    ChangedDate, 
    ChangedTime, 
    ChangedBy
FROM sap.process_order_confirmation_detail
WHERE ...
```